# Sharing Functions between Chrome Extensions

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension (`A`) for Chrome that communicates with another extension (`B`). I want `A` to provide the `B` a function, but it won't send. I can send strings just fine.

`A` has the following code. `rect` is the function in this code.

```
chrome.extension.onRequestExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       obj = {}
       obj.permisions = "all"
       obj.rect = Rect
       alert(obj.permisions+","+obj.rect)
       sendResponse(obj); 
});
```

...this code works just fine. The alert shows a box that says "all", then prints out the function.

`B` has the following code.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(ext[i].id, {}, function(lib) {
    alert(lib.permisions+","+lib.rect)
});
```

The alert on this one shows "all,undefined". Can functions not be passed between extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can certainly [communicate between extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#external), you can only pass valid JSON. Unfortunately, valid JSON only includes simple data types(String, Number, Boolean, Array, Object* or Null).

One way to do it would be to pass the function as a String and use `eval` on the receiving end. Could be unsafe, but *is* doable.

** While a function is technically an `Object`, in this context `Object` refers to name:value pairs of the aforementioned simple data types.*